# Scaffold-DbContext ignores host IP from connection string

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm trying to generate models from an existing PostgreSQL database using this command:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Host=52.0.0.0;Database=my-db;Username=postgres;Password=password" Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL -OutputDir Models
```

It "worked" once by trying to connect to the host but failed because the port 5432 was not accessible.

I fixed the network issue, now the port is opened but the `Host` from the connection string is ignored and the errors I get is:

> 28000: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "my.public.ip.address", user
>   "postgres", database "my-db", SSL off

I don't know why my public address is even mentionned in there, of course I don't have a `pg_hba.conf` file. I'm not the server.

Any ideas ?

Comment: This seems to be the server (PG) complaining that your client's IP address isn't set up for authenticate in its pg_hba.conf file, you need to configure PG to allow you to log in.

Comment: @ShayRojansky Oh I get it, "for host", not "on host". I thought the message meant no conf. file on "my.public.ip.address"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the message wasn't saying that "my.public.address" does not have a pg_hba.conf file, but that there is no configuration in the server for my IP.

```
host    all all     my.public.ip/32     md5
```

This solved it.